# Passing selected item to ajax function

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="addTag" action="#{serverBean.irrelevantMethod(_tagId)}">
   <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{_tagId}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>

<rich:autocomplete autocompleteList="#{tags}" mode="ajax" var="_tag" 
                   fetchValue="#{_tag.id}" onselectitem="addTag();" />
```

The question is related to onselectitem: how to pass the selected item, which should be _tag.id, to the jsFunction 'addTag' as a parameter?

I have tried:

```
onselectitem="addTag('#{_tag.id}')"
```

but it doesn't work.

What I want is to send the selected tag (its id) to server when autocomplete selection occurs. What would be the best way to achieve this if the above is a doomed attempt.

Comment: Which exception is thrown and Which version of the EL expression are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to pass a param like that, but action="#{irrelevantMethod(_tagId)}" will definitely not work. It will try to find it on the server.

Comment: Should be: #{serverBean.irrelevantMethod(_tagId)} and it is meant to be a server bean, which is the whole point of a4j:jsFunction, to make a javascript wrapper to call a server method.

How should I go about this then? To send the selected tagId when autocomplete event "onselectitem" happens?

Comment: Well, serverBean.irrelevantMethod(_tagId) makes more sense. I don't think you had serverBean there before. Why not just add a4j:support to   rich:suggestionbox and send the data to the server that way?

Comment: I didn't have, indeed. It was named 'irrelevant' for that reason :) Sorry to confuse. I use RichFaces 4 btw, so a4j:ajax and rich:autocomplete are what I need with that. I actually changed the approach a bit, and I don't have autocomplete anymore. Well, I still have some problems that I'd like to tackle but another post is needed. Thanks!